# Java httpmessage timer

Tags: java

I'm trying to use httpmessage and a timer. I'm reading a URL an inserting a banner into the code. I want to run a timer for if the user has been on it long enough to refresh the page and re insert the banner. Right now I have it where the user visits the page once and doesn't display the ad again as they browse thought other websites. It only reinserts the banner if the refresh the page.

```
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.nio.charset.*;


// public static int var = 0;
// ---------------
 public static boolean runad = true;

 public void main(HttpMessage httpMessage){
 try{
    //var++;
    //Ignores if not html page
        if (!runad) return;
        runad = false;
        String currentUrl = httpMessage.getUrl(); //Gets the url

        //httpMessage.reply(currentUrl);
        URL cURL = new URL(currentUrl); //creates a connection
        URLConnection c = cURL.openConnection(); //connects to the url throws exception if access denied(e.g. futhead.com)
        String str = c.getContentType();        //Gets type of content html files return text/html css return text/css etc.
        if(str.indexOf("html") == -1) return; //if content type does not have html anywhere in it stop here
     //Get currrent page html
            URL url; //New URL
            InputStream is = null; //New input stream
            BufferedReader br; //New buffer reader
            String line; //Temp string to hold each html line
            String html = ""; //Final string to load all html code
            url = new URL(httpMessage.getUrl()); //Gets the current URL
            is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException opens a new stream
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); //Opens new buffer reader with new stream
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { //reads each line in html and adds it to the ln string
                html = html + StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(line) + "\n";
            }

            html = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(html);

            /*************************Head link injection*******/
            StringBuilder bodyInsert = new StringBuilder();
            String inputLine;
            URL advert = new URL("advertisingurl");
            URLConnection ac = advert.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    ac.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                bodyInsert.append(inputLine+"\n");
            in.close();
            String styleImport = bodyInsert.toString();
            String jsImport = "";
            String jQueryImport = "";
            String bodyImport = "";
            String head; //The beginnnig of the file to right before the </head> tag
            String body; //</head> to right before the </body> tag
            String bEND; //</body> tag to the end of the file
            int hIndex = html.indexOf("</head");  //Index of </head
            int bIndex = html.indexOf("</body"); //Index of </body
            head = html.substring(0, hIndex);
            body = html.substring(hIndex, bIndex);
            bEND = html.substring(bIndex);

            body = body + bodyImport;


            head = head + styleImport + jsImport + jQueryImport;
            String newHTML = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(head + body + bEND);
            newHTML = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(newHTML);
            /*************************Head link injection*******/

            httpMessage.reply(head + body + bEND);
            Test test = new Test();
            test.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 2000);

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            report(10, "Error in test Script", e.getMessage());
        }
     httpMessage.abortProcessing();
 }

public class Test extends TimerTask {

   private int age;

   public Test() {
       Timer timer = new Timer();
       timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 2000);
   }

   /**
    * Implements TimerTask's abstract run method.
    */
    public void run(){
      //toy implementation
        runad = true;
    }

  public void main(String[] args) {
          new Test();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your code please

Comment: There is a javascript code for calculating timespent under "Accurately measure the time spent on each page" heading of this link: https://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide                         Not sure.But may be helpful to you.

Comment: That would not work for me because I want java to time it so that it refreshes the page to reinsert the banner ad